# Android NDK - undefined reference to methods of Prebuilt Shared Library

Tags: android-ndk

First I have made a simple project and then i build that project from ndk-build, it gives me firs-lib.so file. Now i want to use that file as Prebuilt shared Library into my another project. I have updated .mk file.

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := firs-lib-prebuilt
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := libfirs-lib.so
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/include
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := ndk_first
MY_SOURCES := main.c
MY_SOURCES += base.c
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(MY_SOURCES)
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/include
 LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARY := firs-lib-prebuilt
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

ABOVE IS MY Android.mk file
Whenever i try to call a function from Prebuild Shared library it says that undefined reference to method .

Please suggest me something to achieve this.

Comment: Is there any chance that the prebuilt library uses C++?

Comment: No its just with a .h and .c file. There is no CPP code.

Answer (score 0):

Everything is correct except the declaration of the dependency of your module on firs-lib-prebuilt.

Change `LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARY` to `LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES`. That's certainly a grammar mistake since you're setting only one lib, but `LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES` is the only variable that will be considered by the ndk build system :)